# how to refer to object explicitly in method call?

Tags: c++

in a method call on an object, how do i refer to the object itself, explicitly? in the below example, i tried to used "this", but *that* aint good

```
// intended behavior but too "verbose" -
// is it really necessary to create the temporary "s"? 
string s = to_string(rand());
string t = s.substr(s.length() - 6);

// explicity referencing the anonymous object (above example = "s") 
// with "this" doesnt work
string t = to_string(rand()).substr(this->length() - 6); // does not work
```

Comment: "this object" is what is returned from `to_string(rand())` ?

Comment: yes! the anonymous object in the 2nd example is "s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Your code is not "verbose" but it is concise and expresses clearly what you want to do. Sloppy speaking, if you want to refer to the same object in different places the way to go is to give it a name:

```
string s = to_string(rand());
string t = s.substr(s.length() - 6);
```

If you like you could wrap the string into a helper class or write a function that would allow you to write:

```
string t = helper( to_string(rand() , -6);
```

or if you like chaining (helper would create a temporary of some type that converts to string):

```
string t = helper(to_string(rand()).substr(-6);
```

But whether this is more readable is matter of opinions. I wouldn't bother to reinvent a wheel just to save 1 line of code and to sacrifice clarity.

Comment: this example is contrived and maybe not too verbose. in other cases it may be even more convenient to be able to refer explicitly to the object invoked; it may be more succint and concise in that manner.

Comment: @youwouldbesurprised in a more complex example I would instist even more on using a variable

Comment: @youwouldbesurprised what exactly do you hope to gain by cutting it down by one line of code (or some more in a different example)

Comment: isnt function chaining an asset?

Comment: @youwouldbesurprised as I wrote, you can write a helper class that allows for different syntax, but I dont see why you would do that for a `string`

Answer (score 0):

short answer:

```
this->length()
```

explaination:

`this` is a pointer type and therefore has to be dereferenced like any other pointer with `->` or `(*this).`

Comment: thx, unfortunately i get the same error (clang): Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function

Comment: @youwouldbesurprised then please post more code. It seems you are using `this` entirely wrong

Comment: i have updated the syntax to use this-> as you correctly point out. the 2nd example, however still gives the error: Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function. according to @largest_prime... this way of accessing the anonym object simply is not possible.

Comment: @youwouldbesurprised I'd suggest you also add the surrounding function and class to the example. Then it should be pretty clear what's wrong.
`this` can only be used in a member function of a `class`. This seems to be what you are doing.